What kind of pressures would make a culture force its members to always wear power armour
I'm writing a science-fantasy story where there is a culture that forces its members to constantly wear power armor in public. There are different types of armor depending on the specific job the wearer has (e.g. soldiers have thicker plating and more strength and scholars trade augmented strength for data storage). Anyone past adulthood caught not wearing armor in public is exiled or forced into undesirable jobs. Foreigners must wear medieval knight style plate armor and are forced into the same positions as people caught not wearing armor.
What kind of event within the following parameters would force the culture to act like this.

Cannot be caused by some kind of cataclysm or general toxicity of where they live/used to live.
The event only affects this culture.
Has to fit in with the theme of emotional detachment

EDIT:
I should also probably mention that the culture is situated in a very geographically isolated area. It has mountains (With a magical wall created by some unknown force centuries ago running down the middle) on 3 of the 4 sides and a very dangerous ocean to traverse to get anywhere by sea.
EDIT 2 electric boogaloo:
the theme of emotional detachment is that because they are technologically superior to everyone else they are emotionally detached from the worlds struggles. Which manifests in the story as them wearing power armor and hiding their emotions away from the world.

You wouldn't believe the awesome secret handshakes you can do when both are in power armor. Full 720 degree wrist rotation, palm ion cannons, bonus elbows - once you try it you never want to go back.

Please explain "the theme of emotional detachment" more fully. Societal reaction to not wearing armor doesn't fit within the theme of emotional detachment.

the theme of emotional detachment is that because they are technologically superior to everyone else they are emotionally detached from the worlds struggles. Which manifests in the story as them wearing power armor and hiding their emotions away from the world.

They are from off-world, a space-borne culture that retained some high technology and re-colonized the planet after the planetary civilization collapsed. Their habitats standardized on a lower gravity, and those born on them require mechanical assistance and protection from environmental extremes they are unaccustomed to when they return to the homeworld.
Their descendants raised on the homeworld don't physically need the armor, but wear it out of tradition, and to make it harder for outsiders to identify those who were born off-world. It's become the norm to wear it, and outsiders frequently come to them hoping to obtain high-tech armor of their own, which led to the tradition of foreigners having to wear unpowered armor.
The "magic wall" is a remnant of an old spaceport or other installation that they settled around in hopes of salvaging some technology that they themselves didn't retain.

Militaristic society
Power armor can be useful for many things but its main purpose would be as, well, armor. And armor is what you need mainly in an armed conflict. So a society requiring all its citizens to wear battle armor at all times seems to be a very militaristic society.
It's not a conquest-minded society like Rome, but more defensive minded. Think Space Switzerland on steroids, but a lot more militaristic and rather xenophobic. This culture fought many wars in its past defending itself from far more numerous enemy forces, but has always managed to beat back any invading army. Its mountanous isolated geography helped a great deal with that, but it still needed its population to regularly form a militia to defend itself.
Not sure why the place kept getting attacked in spite of its very defensible geography, perhaps there is some really valuable resource that only this place has in any significant quantities. Perhaps this resource helped it achieve its current technological superiority. Now this technological superiority all but guarantees its safety but militarism has become a major part of this place's culture.
Every adult citizen, man or woman, can in theory be drafted into militia to defend this place. Wearing power armor at all times (at least in public) symbolises being ready to join the militia / armed forces at a moment's notice. Not wearing power armor in public is seen as kind of draft dodging which in this very militaristic society is really looked down on. Forcing foreigners to wear medieval-style armor is in part a ritual humiliation ('look how primitive these people's technology is') and in part a reminder to the locals that they're all potential invaders (which is how this civilization sees all foreigners).
'Emotional detachment' thing would go well with militaristic attitude, since in the military you're supposed to follow orders and protocol in a formal and unemotional way.

Perhaps they are like space Israel.  They are a small but wealthy cultural group completely surrounded by a much larger and resentful cultural group that sees them as "colonizers".

Four steps:

They're highly technologically advanced already. They have practically-usable powered armor; I'm willing to bet they also have cybernetics. At some point a while ago, these cybernetics became so ingrained in their culture that it would be financially self-destructive not to have them. "Sorry, Bob, but your regular bio-muscles aren't gonna do the trick. We've decided to hire Alice, who has cybernetically-enhanced CNT musculature, onto the construction team." "Sorry, David. Regular ol' hippocampi aren't suited to the jobs of massive data storage for the new superuniversities. Carol has the new petabyte-drive upgrades, so we're hiring her". That kind of thing.
After a long time of this being the norm, it became not only financially but socially self-destructive not to have extensive cybernetic augmentation.

After cybaugs became the norm, people realized that the outside world would never accept them for what they were - to a cyborg, other cyborgs looked normal, but to normies, they looked unequivocally grotesque. And, being a prideful culture, they decide that wearing power armor is the best way to go - it provides plenty of slots for the cybernetic dendrites and extra limbs to fold into, it looks otherwise pretty sleek, and it helps do the augmentation's job anyway. Who doesn't love a combination beautifying package/extra strength and armor/extra data storage solution?

Of course, power armor has to recharge, since it's way more energy-consuming than cybernetics that can run on batteries for weeks. It becomes sort of like clothing: you wear it outside in public to stay somewhat normal-looking and keep your thousands of cybernetic augmentations packed away, and when you get home you can take it off to recharge it and let your mecha-dendrites hang around a little bit. Leaving your home without power armor to them would be like leaving your home in only underwear to us.

The punishment for public indecency is exile/forced labor. Because why not?


This definitely fits into the theme of emotional detachment as far as I can tell. The Netflix show Altered Carbon and the book it was based on feature extensive cybernetic augmentations, including the ability to just completely leave a body and reenter another one; people become completely detached from their bodies, moralities, and lives because if you get shot, who cares? just get another sleeve (body) and you're fine. Thus the rich generally have augmented bodies of their choosing, and the poor get the old beat-up ones with cancer. Not exactly the same thing, but you get where I'm going: if you can change anything about yourself with cybernetics, what's so special about anyone anymore? Why actually work to improve yourself when you can buy the improvement? Why value your handiwork when someone out there has augmentations specifically designed to mass-produce better versions of it? As a worldbuilder, I'm sure it would be easy to get to the desired theme from here.

Physical atrophy
The suits are fitted to citizens as soon as they stop growing. From that point on the power armor keeps them warm and comfortable, processes waste, enhances their senses, amplifies their speed, strength & reflexes all via direct surgically implanted neuro-links with the relevant parts of the brain. You think it? The suit does it. The suits also provides fully immersive access to a virtual reality internet, AI advice/support and of course fellow citizens. In addition? the suit monitors key health functions and alerts the user to the need for the need of specific medical treatments in case of  infections or cancer etc. Reproduction is via artificial insemination and you spend the rest of your life in the your suit with parts being replaced as needed.)
However after a few months occupants muscles will start to atrophy due to lack of use along with other bodily functions that are being underutilized due to direct physical interface with the suit. After a few years? Occupants can't physically move without the assistance of the suit. It becomes in effect more a life support system than something you just wear.

I was going to write a similar comment.  A good reason for this to be done in spite of the obvious downside is having colonized a high-g world.  Nothing crazy like a 10g planet is required, just that the assistive tech was necessary at first just to move around for a full day's work colonizing and culturally it became more and more accepted to "keep your work boots on" as it were.  As people spend more time in their armor, it gets more involved and specialized and then you've got folks never moving and needing it 24/7.

There have been and there are still today societies where social norms are very strict in prescribing people's attire.
Think of Tokugawa period Japan, where each class had to dress appropriately for its status.
Usually the reasoning behind such norms is that they support social order and stability, and often emerge after a period of turmoil.

The magic walls sometimes spawn horrors beyond most peoples comprehension, slaugthering humans like some people eat watermelons.
Our scientists invented power armour, giving us the upper hand. We will not be defeated, we shall be victorious. We shall train our people, we will be VICTORIOUS.
To be killed by a magical spawn is a disgrace! Not wearing your sacred armour is blasphomy, we will not tolerate weakness, WE WILL BE VICTORIOUS.

Doesn't even have to be horrors.  There's some sort of gateway to another universe in the area, stuff sometimes comes through.  It can't survive long here but it's pretty dangerous for a while and people need to be able defend themselves.  Going unarmored is not just a risk to you, but because the critters have a toxin that causes extreme paranoia you become a danger to everyone around.

I'm reminded of another culture that sounds somewhat similar: The Mandalorian Children of the Watch

 

From The Mandalorian S1E4:

Cara Dune: So, what happens if you take that thing off? They come after you and kill you?
The Mandalorian: No. You just can't ever put it back on again.

The "thing" they're referring to in that scene is the Mandalorian's helmet. In that culture, the Mandalorians who follow teachings of the Children of the Watch are similarly exiled for removing their helmets in public.
Now to get to your question, what would cause your culture to develop this way? The establishment of your people creating an enclave for themselves. The general populace did not like your people wearing power armor in public even if your people didn't wear it all the time. It made them feel uneasy due to the sheer difference in strength between normal civilians and your people. The anonymity of the helmets also provided an unintentional intimidation towards the general populace. Relations continued to decline over time and led to your people becoming unpopular and marginalized in society. As a result, they decided to band together and form an enclave for themselves. However, this was extremely unpopular to society at-large. Hostilities grew to an all-time high and there was an incident involving a foreigner in the enclave which caused the death of several of your people who were vulnerable because they weren't wearing the power armor.
Your people swore never again. They just want to live their lives and be left alone. They began to wear their armor at all times to always be ready to defend each other and also to intimidate outsiders from incurring the wrath of the enclave. Foreigners to the enclave are required to wear the lesser medieval-style armor to show that they are friend, not foe. The long period of high-tensions from forming the enclave to ensuring its continuing existence led to their culture always wearing their armor to protect each other, deter threats, and determine allegiance.

This is the way.

A: Lobbyism
The manufacturer of power armors plays a big part in your culture. It is not allowed, by law, to not wear their armor. Every citizen needs to have one. They sell it, maintain it and repair it.
B: Identification
Power armors have an interface for identification and communication. They store your personal information and keep track of your credit score. You can not be a part of the community without the required ID-Interface.

This matches what I was going to mention - cars in the USA, with the legal framework forcing big parking lots, inflated distances, and multi-lane roads that promote speeding. Add no sidewalks, transit or bike lanes, making it more risky and more difficult to travel without a car in many parts of the country.

The best science fiction employs what's called cognitive estrangement - the recontextualizing of something very familiar to make it "weird" and force us to think about it.
Your power armor concept is analogous to something that's extremely common in American society: the automobile. While technically cars have multiple seats, the majority are driven by just one occupant.
Due to infrastructure adapting over the course of a century to accommodate cars at the cost of every other mode of transit, the car has come to be romanticized as a guarantor of independence (ignoring the reliance on publicly funded roads, and a massive refueling network). A driver can go anywhere on the "open road" while a pedestrian is a sorry individual indeed, subject to the whims of the municipal government's bus or train schedules.
So there's your power armor: in a society even more libertarian that the car-based one, any adult who is fit as a breadwinner demonstrates that by wearing a personal suit that has a fully controlled atmosphere within which they are undisputed master. The "armor" part doesn't have to be mandatory but when you think about today's SUVs - a feedback loop of higher danger from heavy vehicles and more protection adding more weight has produced veritable monsters on the streets. All the people who are unable to secure themselves within an armored shell clearly need protecting, for their own good (via exile or essentially an insane asylum/prison).

Technologically superior
You've given the answer yourself already. In a society where technology and intelligence is seen as the pinnacle, they could loathe some biological processes. Some biological processes are unavoidable, but easily to remedy. Hunger influences your cognition a lot, so is undesirable. With technology food can be abundant and thus not an issue. Things less controlled are fear and physical desires. You can remove sexual desire for a great part if you're not exposed to those stimuli. You can make someone think rationally in tense situations if you put them in a power suit. You can prevent exposure to sexual traits by covering them up with power armour.
Being technologically superior can lead to distancing themselves from the physical, or at least trying to. Anything that can influence their use or advancement of technology abhorrent to the culture. Anyone, guest or otherwise, should not expose themselves or the locals to anything less than rational thought.

“You can prevent exposure to sexual traits by covering them up with power armour.” doesn't work in practice: people invent proxy metrics and sexualise those. (Obligatory xkcd.)

@wizzwizz4 You are right. I was thinking of adding it, but decided it detracted from the whole. Sexuality is expressed in many ways, from ankles to thighs to breasts to hair in different cultures and their attires. It will find a way, even if only the eyes are visible or something. That being said, there is overt and covert sexuality, where covert can still reduce the amount of stimuli. Not only that, they can focus on a more cerebral sexuality. Think cleverly hidden sexual messages, which can be seen as emotional detachment. Regadless, just like hunger, they might agree you need to eat..

Air.  So you've got them on a mountain.  It's entirely plausible that this started purely because of air pressure.
It's just easier, for manual and heavy work to use an environment suit that provides higher pressure air to breath.  And you might as well add some power assistance, because carrying 15kg of environmental gear is hard.
Over the years, as there were more and more people, living higher and higher up the mountains it moved from manual workers to everyone.
Because dying from altitude sickness sucks.
And then it because fashionable!

Hypoxia might fall afoul the OP's first criterion - "cannot be caused by some kind of general toxicity of where they live". I don't think the power armor can be required as a type of life support, although whether it's life support or merely a convenience will depend on the altitude.

Toxicity isn't the same thing, but I agree it's possible that the OP might have meant that.

Conservative society that doesn't want to be left behind
Your world is set in the future. In this future, cybernetics and augmented humans are the norm in the whole world.
It means that the workforce is stronger, faster, has enhanced senses (depending on their augments)... All this leads to enhanced productivity everywhere, but also forces people that still want to have a normal professional life to augment themselves. The ones that don't want to are left behind because they can't compete in the job market.
but
Your specific culture is very conservative. They see their body as sacred, and thus can't make any augmentation on them. It leaves them with two options :

Keep living their lives as before. This will make them less efficient than other cultures, leaving them in the long run as left behind technologically, economically, and vulnerable.
Use Power Armor. All the strength/speed/sense that they are missing from their lack of augments, the Power Armor makes up for it. They are still competitive and keep their body pristine :-)

Not using your Power Armor in public is a problem because :

It makes you weak compared to the others
It might be a sign that you are one of those extremists that doesn't want to use Power Armor, and is only a burden to society
It might be a sign that you are actually part of the "impure augmented people"

In such a society, foreigners are necessarily augmented. Due to the difference in beliefs, they are seen as "impure" and thus need a mandatory difference so that everyone can identify them and avoid too close relationship with them.
As they are augmented, they don't need a Power Amor. They don't need it, are not worthy of it and wouldn't know how to use it anyway. A simple medieval armor is sufficient.

HISTORY AND TRADITION.
In the times of the forefathers of our forefathers, we were a brave nation of warriors. So good at shedding blood, that other kingdoms would would often hire us as mercenaries, to fight their battles, and defend their homes. Our beautiful plate armor became our pride and mark of honor.
But the soft people of the soft kingdoms resented us for our strength. When the Great Famine came, and millions died to the invisible enemy of hunger, the Soft People closed their gates on us. Fearing our strength, they hid in their fortified towns and castles, surviving off their supplies, while we, their armored protectors, were starving to death.
The Soft People said nobody in armor was allowed inside their cities, fearing we would kill them to take their food. They said we must strip our armor off, and sell it to them for food, and that we need to approach their gates naked and unarmed.
We refused, because we had honor, and ninety and nine of every hundred of us perished.
The survivors vowed to never take our armor off, never show weakness. And the next time the Soft People were in danger, and called for us to help, we closed our hearts, and our ears, the way they closed their gates before.
You might ask, why do we hold the grudge still, since millennia had passed? Why do we keep the armor on? My answer is, with each generation our suits of armor improved, and in time, its iron fused with the iron of our souls. Your armor is your skin, your castle, your home and your soul. You are not a being of flesh and blood clad in armor, you are a suit of armor wrapped over meager flesh.

It is better to have it and never need it, than to need it and not have it...
And massive Medical costs...
Even in a modern western world, there are a myriad of things that exist that can kill us. Cars, Branches falling, even slipping on concrete can crack a persons skull and result in Death.
This society places a very high value on Life and Well-Being and so once Powered Armour became both readily available and practical, declared that it is mandatory to be worn to protect it's citizenry.
The philosophical basis for this is to look at things such as Seatbelt laws, Motorcycle Helmet laws etc.
And so the Government made it a rule that every adult must wear armour.
In addition to this - there is a secondary element - Medical treatment and specifically time not working/contributing to society for accidental medical issues is frowned upon. Society does not begrudge someone who has contracted a virus etc. But it does take very unkindly to the guy on the ladder doing a bit of DIY who didn't want to move the ladder a couple more inches to the left...
The reason for this is that the Society has a completely socialized medical system and so any accident is paid for by the State - The wearing of Power Armour allowed them to decrease the budget for this health system significantly by eliminating a lot of accidental injuries - and therefore this became the law.

It's an Indecent Exposure law
Every culture has a different definition of physical modesty, and most cultures have laws about a minimum standard of dress when out in the world.  Real world societies range from clothing optionally all the way to not being able to show anything more than your eyes, and everything in between.  In your society, textile clothing is considered indecent because it conforms to shape of the body underneath it and flows in provocative ways.  In contrast, ridged attire like power armor (or even the plate armor those poor immigrants have to use) serves to make the curves and flow of a person's body completely obscured in a way that textile cloth does not.
Strict indecency laws tend to go hand in hand with emotionally detached societies because modesty is a consequence of not feeling okay with emotions such as arousal and feeling the need to legislate to protect people from feeling things.
It's also tied into your caste system
The reason for power armor specifically is because your society has a caste system as well.  There were many societies in history where certain clothing options were restricted to specific castes of people.  Rome for example evolved complex laws around clothing as a way for people to know who was what in an age when those things mattered a lot on the day-to-day, but you would not always know everyone of authority when you meet them.
That said, even though it is kind of common in history for the poor to be punished for dressing like the elite, it was not common for the elite to be punished for dressing like the poor, but there was an acception to this with La Cour Royale de France.  Louis XIV felt that the members of his court would be easier to keep in line if they had to follow strict rules of edicate; so, he was very strict about how the top members of his society had to dress and behave because it forced them to be ever vigilant of thier obedience.
So making citizens ware specific types of armor servers 3 rolls: it enforces cultural norms, it helps with identifying status, and it helps the highest level of leadership exert strict control over the lower nobility/middle class.

They are allergic to everything. After a certain threshold is reached, everything in nature becomes hyper-hostile towards civilization. Every creature becomes intelligent, every plant becomes hyper allergic and spewing death in all directions. Its a arms-race after all and if nature gets enough time to catch up, it will throw all it can at you on a planet.
Somewhere something is drilling into a habitat on a death world, to say hello and enjoy the comforts. There is no long-term survival for any smart species on any planet. They all become hostile death traps shortly after the emergence of industrial civilization. Those not rich and able to flee to space, have to up there game constantly. One of those factors is powerarmor. As safe space is at a premium and only constant movement prevents the hyper-hostile parallel evolution from keeping up.
